# android form validation Edittext focus one by one if condition true

Tags: android, validation

How to validate form firstname is true then focus next Edittext  the true next field as like this, if previous field empty don't go next field. please help me to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Not clear what you are asking here. What you wrote makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: I say validation form Firstname field not empty then middle name type enable the type

Comment: can validate foreach  instanceof this way

Answer (score 1):

Use testChangeListener for that edit text field.

```
        editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            editText2.requestFocus();
        }
    });
```

Comment: but I have multiple field , every time write ?

Comment: can I validate Array Edittext loop ,etc

Comment: try this is xml `android:nextFocusDown="@+id/nextEdittext"
`

Answer (score 1):

You can set onClick listener to every editText. When an edittext is clicked then it will check if it's previous field is empty or valid

```
editTextLastName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View view) {
                          if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextFirstName.getText())){
                                 Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Please fill up the first name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                 editTextFirstName.requestFocus();
                            }
                       }
                   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding text watcher like this and its just an idea and format that based on your requirement

```
 etfirstname.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String getPickupPlace = s.toString();
            String stringEditText = etfirstname.getText().toString().trim();

            if (etPickup.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0) {
                etfirstname.setClickable(false);
                etfirstname.setEnabled(false);
                etfirstname.setFocusable(false);

            } else {
                etfirstname.setClickable(true);
                etfirstname.setEnabled(true);
                etfirstname.setFocusable(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check condition using edittext addTextChangedListener like:

```
    editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if(<condition>){
             editText2.requestFocus();
        }
    }
});
```

provide that event for all edittext and set the flow of your navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Valdidate your each field (editText) one by one like this:

```
    editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_enter_name);
    editTextmob= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_mobNo);
    editTextEmail= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_email);


        if (editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please enter username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else if (editTextmob.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please enter your mobile number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else if (editTextmob.getText().length() < 10) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please enter valid mobile number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
        else if (!editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        {
            if (!android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(
                    editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim()).matches()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter valid e-mail id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            else {

            //Do your stuff here
            }
        }
```